# Error in Basic User Permissions in Django blog

Tags: python, django

My simple Django blog don't work - if I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/create/ I see

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:    GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/create/
Raised by:    posts.views.post_create
```

Looking in the git history I understand what error in posts/views.py.

The file itself looks like this

```
from urllib.parse import quote
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Post
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.shortcuts import render


def post_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, 'Successfully Created')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        'form': form,

    }
    return render(request, 'posts/post_form.html', context)


def post_detail(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    share_string = quote(instance.content)
    context = {
        'title': instance.title,
        'instance': instance,
        'share_string': share_string
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/post_detail.html', context)


def post_list(request):
    queryset_list = Post.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 5)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    queryset = paginator.get_page(page)
    context = {
        'object_list': queryset,
        'title': 'List'
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/post_list.html', context)


def post_update(request, id=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,
                    instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, '<a href="#">Item</a>Saved',
                         extra_tags='html_safe')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        'title': instance.title,
        'instance': instance,
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'posts/post_form.html', context)


def post_delete(request, id=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    instance.delete()
    messages.success(request, 'Successfully Deleted')
    return redirect('posts:list')
```

I think error in `if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser` line.
Because after this line, if I understand correctly from history, django-blog not work.
django.VERSION - (2, 0, 1, 'final', 0)
Thank you very much.

Comment: what are you trying to do if the user is not staff and not superuser? you have mentioned to show 404 , so what do you need

Comment: raising an `HTTP 404` error because the requested user is not a `staff` and `superuser`